# Deriving a given result of a Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am going over the proof of the Cauchy–Kovalevskaya theorem using analytic majorization (for the second order PDE case) and I am unable to derive the result given by equation $(4)$. The details are as follows.

Consider $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{mMp}{p-mu}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\quad\text{and}\quad u(0,y)=\frac{My}{p-y}\quad\quad\quad(1),$$ where $u=(x,y)$ and $M,m,p$ are constants.

Consider $v=\frac{mMpx}{p-mu}+y$ such that the first part of Equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0.\quad\quad\quad(2)$$

Equation $(2)$ shows that Jacobian of the functions $u,v$ with respect to the variables $x,y$ is zero. Hence, $u,v$ are functionally dependent and as such the general solution of $(1)$ is of the form $$u=\phi(v)=\phi\left(\frac{mMpx}{p-mu}+y\right),\quad\quad\quad(3)$$ where $\phi$ is an arbitrary function of the one variable $v$. The initial condition given in the second part of Equation $(1)$ shows that $$\phi(y)=\frac{My}{p-y}$$ and therefore, we derive from $(3)$ the relation

> $$(mp-my)u^2-(p^2+mMy-py-mMpx)u+Mpy+mM^2px=0\quad\quad\quad(4),$$

defining $u$ as a function of $x,y$.

Thanks.